# How can I support multiresolution in cocos2d Android?

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android

I am now working on a cocos2d Android game. During this game's development, I've faced some problems. This game runs in perfectly in Galaxy Tab, but when I run this game on a small device, the images do not appear properly.

How can I resolve this problem? I put all my all images in the assets folder.

Comment: you have to find the screen size and apply the cases on it and according to the screen size , choose the photo from assets ...

Comment: do you have any example for this in android cocos2d game...